# Send message when failed(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, messaging

Im trying to simulate two machines working, and failing at random times. When they fail they call assistance. These two machines is part of bigger system of different machines, which needs to know when its neighbor has failed to do its job.

So far, I have made the simulate of the two machines, but I cant figure out how to send messages to their neighbors without each machine needing to know the whole system?

This is what I have so far:

```
import simpy
import random



random_seed=42
MTTF = 3500
break_mean = 1 / MTTF
sim_time = 4 * 7*24*60 # 4 weeks 24/7
num_machines = 2
rep_time = 30
tpp = 20 #20 minutes to make each part
neighbour = 3 #How many should it send to?


#Creating a class called messaging which is an object.
class messaging(object):
#DEfing the initilizing function, and initilize self, Environment, and       capacity which is set to infinity, by a simpy core-function.
    def __init__(self, env, capacity=simpy.core.Infinity):
        self.env = env
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.pipes = []

#Making a function which work on everything that is a part of the message. With name Put.
    def put(self, value):

        if not self.pipes: #How to get this error?
            raise  runtime_error('There are no output pipes.')
        #Create a variable, events, store to it pipe values
        events = broken_machine()
        return self.env.all_of(events)

    def get_output_conn(self):
        #Set the capacity of pipe variable to store infinity.
        pipe = simpy.Store(self.env, capacity=self.capacity)
        #to each pipes, add(or append) pipe
        self.pipes.append(pipe)
        return pipe

def mesg_generator(number, env, out_pipe):
    msg = ('Failed')

def message_reciever(name, env, in_pipe):
    while True:
        msg = yield in_pipe.get()

        print("%s received message: %s" % (number, msg[1]))

def time_per_part():
    return tpp

def ttf():
    return random.expovariate(break_mean)


class Machine(object):

    def __init__(self, env, number, repair):
    #self.arg = arg
        self.env = env
        self.number = number
        self.parts_made = 0
        self.times_broken = 0
        self.broken = False

        self.process = env.process(self.working(repair))
        env.process(self.broken_machine())


def working(self, repair):
    while True:
        work = time_per_part()
        while work:
            try:
                begin = self.env.now
                yield self.env.timeout(work)
                work = 0
            except simpy.Interrupt:
                self.broken = True
                work -= self.env.now - begin

                with repair.request(priority = 1) as req:
                    yield req
                    yield self.env.timeout(rep_time)
                self.times_broken +=1
                yield message_reciever()
                #print('Machine down')
                self.broken = False #Machine fixed again

        self.parts_made +=1

def broken_machine(self):
    while True:
        yield self.env.timeout(ttf())
        if not self.broken:
            self.process.interrupt()

def other_jobs(env, repair):
    while True:
        work = tpp
        while work:
            with repair.request(priority=2) as req:
                yield req
                try:
                    begin = env.now
                    yield env.timeout(work)
                    work = 0
                 except simpy.Interrupt:
                    work -= env.now - begin


print("This simulates machines 3 and 4 doing the same tasks.")

random.seed(random_seed)

env = simpy.Environment()
pipe = simpy.Store(env)
bc_pipe = messaging(env)
repair = simpy.PreemptiveResource(env, capacity = 1)
machines = [Machine(env, 'Machine %d' % i, repair)
            for i in range(num_machines)]
env.process(other_jobs(env, repair))
env.run(until=sim_time)

#Show how many times each machine failed:
for machine in machines:
    print("%s broke down %d times" %(machine.number, machine.times_broken))
```

Comment: Why do you unintentional all of the functions after __init__ so that they are not in the class?

Comment: thats just an error made when typing it in here.

Comment: Your message functions don't take self.